Spring security with react for login authentication error
--------------------------Spring security code-------------------------------
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource){
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);

        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery(
                "select user_id,pw,active from members where user_id=?"
        );
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                "select user_id,role from roles where user_id=?"
        );

        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(configurer -> {
                    configurer
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"api/employees").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"api/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"api/employees/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"api/employees").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(form -> {
                    form
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                            .failureForwardUrl("/")
                            .permitAll();
                })
                .logout(logout -> {
                    logout
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                            .permitAll();
                })
        ;

        //use Http basic authentication
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        //disable cross site request forgery(CSFR)
        //not required for stateless rest api that use get,post,put,patch,delete
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


-------------------------------React login page-------------------------------------
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', new URLSearchParams({
        username: username,
        password: password
      }), { withCredentials: true });
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        navigate('/home');
      } else {
        console.error('Login failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login failed:', error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5" align="center">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form>
          <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="username"
                label="Username"
                name="username"
                autoComplete="username"
                autoFocus
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Button
                type="button"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleLogin}
              >
                Sign In
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Login;


Even though the passsword is wrong ,it is still redirecting to home page and in chrome console it is showing status 200. But when i check my api only using postman or localhost:8080/login authenticaton wokrs fine but with react(localhost:5173/login) redirect even wrong user to home page.

You need to user FormData https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Using_FormData_Objects hence the name FORMlogin. Not UrlSearchParams

BTW: .loginProcessingUrl("/login") That's the defaul, remove this line. .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll  you alread permitted it, remoce this line.
